# MochaJS: how to preview request body in console?

Tags: javascript, api, request, mocha.js

I often use variables in my API tests, sometimes ive got code 400 instead of code 200 and problem is in bad values of variables.
How can I preview request body with variables or headers in console.log? I tried 'console.log('req body: '+request.body)', but it's not working, it will be very helpful in test error diagnostics

```html
   it('should return token for authorized user', function(done) {
    request
      .post('/rest/v1/auth/with-password')
      .set(config.headers)
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + auth_token) 
      //.set('Accept', 'application/json')  
      .send({
        "email" : user,
        "password" : password
      })
      .end(function(err,res){
        console.log('req body: '+request.body)
        assert.equal(res.status,200)
        assert.property(res.body,'token')
        assert.isString(res.body.token)
        assert.equal(res.body.user.email,user)
        assert.isFalse(res.body.user.locked)
        auth_token=res.body.token
        console.log('authorized token: '+auth_token) 
        
        done(err)
      });       
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

answer is `console.log(res.request)` :)